Unity 2D colliders pass through
I have a ball rotating in the center of player (its child of player). The game is simple. Ball will collide with walls and get player higher and make it pass the parkour. But sometimes ball pass through colliders.
Here is the video of the problem:
https://streamable.com/0et3wt
The code of rotation:
transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.forward,  rot * Time.deltaTime);
I try to add Rigidbody2D and change some settings but it didn't worked. I'll need a solution that ball will never pass through the collider. If you want to help and need more info about the code or etc. give comment and I'll sent.

When using a Rigidbody you are agreeing to no longer modify the transform directly, and let it be controlled only by the rigidbody. By rotating using the transform collisions will be ignored.
Instead, rotate your object through Rigidbody.MoveRotation(), or better: Rigidbody.AddTorque().

This also applies to moving your cubes, which to my eye also look like they might also be having their transforms modified directly.

The rotating ball has no rigidbody2D because rb doesn't have a method like RotateAround

You can't have it both ways unfortunatley. If you want physics collisions then you'll have to use the physics engine (rigidbody, colliders, move objects by forces). The maths for a circle path is pretty simple, or you can use unity's physics joints.
